# Kotlin NoArgs Constructor for Data Classes with Value Class Property

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have a value class `Id`:

```kotlin
@JvmInline
value class Id private constructor(val value: String) {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @JsonCreator
        fun generate() = Id(randomUUID().toString())
    }
}
```

And a simple data class:

```kotlin
data class TestDataClass(
    var id: Id? = null,
    var string: String? = null,
)
```

According to the docs, since all properties have default value, Kotlin compiler should generate a default constructor but it doesn't:

```java
// Fails with NoSuchMethodException
System.out.println(TestDataClass.class.getConstructor());
```

Now, if you change the `Id` class to a normal one, it does create the default constructor.
It gets even weirder when you add [no-args](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html) plugin. The above code still doesn't work, however removing the default value like below gets you the default constructor (presumably by the plugin?):

```kotlin
@NoArgs
data class TestDataClass(
    var id: Id,
    var string: String? = null,
)
```

Also if you make the `Id` class a normal one, everything works as expected!

Any idea what's going on? (It seem like a bug to me, but wanted to check here before reporting it.)

Update: Already filed a Kotlin bug report.

Comment: Which docs say Kotlin should generate a no arg constructor?

Comment: “On the JVM, if all of the primary constructor parameters have default values, the compiler will generate an additional parameterless constructor which will use the default values.” https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html